# Facebook auto post to user wall

Tags: facebook

Have you noticed when you visit some sites, whatever content you access there, is posted on your Facebook wall automatically? Sites like YouTube, MySpace, Yahoo, socialcam, Viddy etc all used this kind of script or app.

*How did they do it and how can I do one too?*

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) specifically the [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

[image: Open Graph layout]

Answer (score -1):

1. Login to your account
2. Goto https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy
3. Click "Timeline and Tagging" - Edit settings
4. Set "Who can post on your timeline?" as "No One"...